# How to know I'm leaving from a location

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, geolocation, core-location

I'm using Core Location with ios 6.
I have been searching for this but could find an appropriate soln

My question is:
- How can I know if I am leaving point X (after I cross it)?

Comment: you can find when latitude and longitude changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

CLLocation *curPos = locationManager.location;

latitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:curPos.coordinate.latitude] floatValue];

longitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:curPos.coordinate.longitude] floatValue];

if (ABS( latitude - XlocationLAT)>0.1 ||ABS( longitude - XlocationLON)>0.1 ) {
    NSLog(@"He is out");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Geo Fence API

[CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3a)

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0) radius:100.0 identifier:@"Identifier"];
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

then track changes in delegate methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {}
```

and do not forget to enable background mode UIBackgroundModes.

Comment: The UIBackgroundModes is not necessary. It will really use a lot of battery life. It is recommended to use significant location changes if you can tolerate the precision.